# Count Rows in Array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, count

I would like to count values in array however it kept returning nonetype has no len(). Probably I might be missing an exception.

```
Table = [a, b, c]
Table_value = len(table)
For I in range(0, table_value):
Table.append(x)
```

Comment: your list is Table, you call len on table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction on your code,

```
Table = [a, b, c]
Table_value = len(Table) #here you passed "table" while your variable name is "Table"
For I in range(0, Table_value):
Table.append(x)
```

Try the above code, it might give you a solution for the error you are getting as "nonetype has no len()", you may be getting this error as you are using variable names other than what you have initiated.
As python is dynamically typed, so you are not getting direct error for wrong variable name.
But the compiler knows that The len() method only works on iterable objects such as strings, lists, and dictionaries. This is because iterable objects contain sequences of values. If you try to use the len() method on a None value, you’ll encounter the error “TypeError: object of type ‘NoneType’ has no len()”

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
Table = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Table_value = len(Table)
print(Table_value)
```

Returns the result as `3` that is length of the array

Comment: Yes, I had this when it returns value. If the table array doesn’t contain any value, how can I catch it as an exception or return it successfully? I got it to work when there are values but without it, it return nonetype has no len.

Comment: @moomoo In the case when you your array is Empty then the len(Table) will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well the variable you entered is not the same as the list you declared.
That's why interpreter raised the error.
Happy :-) Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
table = [a, b, c]
table_value = len(table)
for i in range(0, table_value):
    table.append(x)
```

Python is a case-sensitive language. table and Table are different variables. As well table_value and Table_value